# JavaMail Recipients - encoding problem?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have small problem with JavaMail. Sometimes method getRecipients from class Message returns weird thing, a part of mycode:

```
Message m = parent.getAgent().getMessages()[size-row-1];
m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)[0].toString();
```

for some messages I have proper value like:

```
Pracuj.pl <pracuj@emails.pracuj.pl>
```

while some are like:

```
=?ISO-8859-2?Q?Jakas_Nazwa?= <jakas_nazwa@costam.pl>
```

Any idea what might be the problem? Maybe coding of Polish chars (ISO 8859-2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely an encoding issue. Try calling [MimeUtility#decodeText](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decodeText%28java.lang.String%29) on the returned recipient string.